# Which is the best way to add a profile picture code for users in a website

Tags: ruby, html

Hi I'm creating a website which has many users, I would like add a profile picture for every user and display it. Which is the best way to add either using server scripting (Ruby) or via HTML and java scripts?

Comment: Do you want to write scripts in Java or do you want to write in Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest way to do this (independently of any technology) is to have your website use [Gravatars](https://en.gravatar.com/) ("Globally Recognized Avatars") when available. You can then use a simple img to show it in any size you want :

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50" />
```

See [here](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) for more information.